# Python can't load JSON created by json.dump

Tags: python, json

This seems to be a very straightforward problem where I am trying to read a JSON file and modify a few of the fields.

```
with open("example.json", "r+") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    # perform modifications to data
    f.truncate(0)
    json.dump(data, f)
```

It worked the first time I manually created a JSON file and stored the correct JSON file, but by the second time I run the same script it gives me this error:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Why is that? It surprises me that the `json` module cannot parse the file created by the module itself.

Comment: Could you post the file contents?

Comment: @Chris The original JSON file I manually made with vim only contains `{}`. The script did perform the expected modifications and stored the correct JSON string back to the file (without a newline at the end.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of the code looks like, but `f.truncate` clears the file, it does not return your file cursor back to the beginning of the file. If you are looking to bring the cursor back to the beginning of the file you are looking for `f.seek(0)`.

Comment: So you started with a manually created file, ran your code, then ran it again and the 2nd time you ran it got the error?

Comment: @Chris That is correct.

Comment: @idjaw Doesn't `.truncate(0)` truncate the file to 0 bytes and thus clearing the content?

Comment: Try running your code and checking the file at the end. It adds extra characters to the front of the file

Comment: @idjaw I think you are right, `.truncate` only removes the content but didn't reset the cursor. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Exactly. `truncate` *truncates* the file to that many bytes. By specifying 0, you are pretty much setting it to 0 bytes.

Comment: @Chris Seems like it. Interesting that `cat example.json` didn't print out the extra characters.

Comment: Maybe use 'json.dumps ()'??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, and what you are trying to do (return the file cursor back to the beginning of the file), you are not actually doing that with `f.truncate`. You are actually *truncating* your file. i.e. Clearing the file entirely.

Per the `help` on the `truncate` method:

```
truncate(...)
    truncate([size]) -> None.  Truncate the file to at most size bytes.

    Size defaults to the current file position, as returned by tell().
```

What you are actually looking to do with returning the cursor back to the beginning of the file is using `seek`.

The help on seek:

```
seek(...)
    seek(offset[, whence]) -> None.  Move to new file position.
```

So, explicitly, to get back to the beginning of the file you want `f.seek(0)`.

For the sake of providing an example of what is happening. Here is what happens with truncate:

File has stuff in it:

```
>>> with open('v.txt') as f:
...  res = f.read()
...
>>> print(res)
1
2
3
4
```

Call `truncate` and see that file will now be empty:

```
>>> with open('v.txt', 'r+') as f:
...  f.truncate(0)
...
0
>>> with open('v.txt', 'r') as f:
...  res = f.read()
...
>>> print(res)

>>>
```

Using `f.seek(0)`:

```
>>> with open('v.txt') as f:
...  print(f.read())
...  print(f.read())
...  f.seek(0)
...  print(f.read())
...
1
2
3
4



0
1
2
3
4


>>>
```

The long gap between the first output shows the cursor at the end of the file. Then we call the `f.seek(0)` (the `0` output is from the `f.seek(0)` call) and output our `f.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one line, `f.seek(0)`

```
with open("example.json", "r+") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    # perform modifications to data
    f.seek(0);
    f.truncate(0)
    json.dump(data, f)
```